# How is the Notes app Details screen designed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I am working on a Popover view that shows a few settings similar to what the iOS note app does when you tap the info icon next to a note. However, I am quite new to iOS development and I'm a bit unsure how that view is composed.

Take the "Remind me on a day" section. Is that just a static UIView with a UILabel and a switch, or is it actually a 1-row tableView with a custom cell?

[image]

Comment: The whole screen is probably one `UITableViewController` (grouped style, 3 sections) with customized cells.

Comment: How would you go about handling user interaction with the different rows?

Comment: You will have to be more specific. The question as it stands is very very broad.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a grouped table view and then use the individual controls such as the switch and segment control as accessoryView for each table view cell. 
Or you can design this entire screen in the nib or storyboard itself using static cells. Then you can connect their target/action to your table view controller class and add the appropriate code.

Answer (score 1):

A UITableView, with Content set to 'Static Cells' and Style set to 'Grouped' in interfaced builder.  There are 3 sections, with 1 cell in the 1st section, 1 in the second, and 3 in the 3rd.  The sections have no titles.  It's embedded in a navigation controller to provide the 'Settings' title and 'Done' button.

[image]

Comment: In my attribute inspector there is not "Content" option. Is there a particular reason for that? I've noticed this before but never figured it out.